# why questionmark comes in the end of filename when i create .txt file through shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am writing one shell script in which I am supposed to create 1 text file. When I do this, a question mark comes at the end of file name. what is the reason?

I am trying below methods in bash script.

1) `grep ERROR a1* > text.txt`

2) `touch text.txt`

In both the methods, instead of `text.txt`, there is a file generated as `text.txt?`

what should I do to overcome this?

Comment: try dos2unix to your script and then retry.

Comment: dos2unix: command not found showing.

Comment: On my machine, sometimes the name of a file is succeeded by a `*` as defined by some file permissions. Can you try to modify those?

Comment: I have modified with 755, 777. still not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you script uses `\r\n` as line endings, this is typical DOS style line endings. Unix like systems uses `\n`. You should try to change the line feeds, eg with your favorite text editor:

```
vim +'set ff=unix | x' my_script
```

Or with `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix my_script
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' my_script
```

Comment: dos2unix myfile.sh worked for me.