# Question marks appears at the end of text file on renaming the text file

Tags: perl, rename

I was trying to download a link through Perl script which is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
use LWP::UserAgent();
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::LinkExtor;
my $path = abs_path();

print "please provide input link from above for example https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/ASSEMBLY_REPORTS/prokaryote_type_strain_report.txt\n";
defined(my $link = <>) or die "unable to take arguments from command line $!";
         
my $string = "$link";
$string  =~ s/(.*)\///;
my $text_file = print $';
getstore($link, "$path/links_ncbi/$text_file") or die "unable to get required text file $!\n";

rename("$path/links_ncbi/1", "$path/links_ncbi/$'") or die "unable to rename text file $!\n";
```

It did the job; it downloaded the required text file in the required directory, but when I try to rename it using the function `rename`, it also did that.  But, I always get a question mark behind the name of the text file as follows:

```
prokaryote_type_strain_report.txt?
```

constants of the file are same.  I checked it, but the only thing is the "?".  Please tell me why that happens and how to fix it. I also tried the following solutions:

```
vim +'set ff=unix | x' test.pl
```

and

```
dos2unix test.pl
```

also, I tried

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' test.pl
```

As the solution was mentioned in the previously asked question but was for specific for the bash script but tried it on Perl script this didn't work.

I also tried to check it and did the following:-

```
 print qq{rename("$path/links_ncbi/1", "$path/links_ncbi/$'")} or die "unable to rename text file $!\n";
```

but everything seems fine, please tell me where I am doing wrong and why this "?" appears on renaming the file, your help is much needed and appreciated.
thankyou.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566064/why-questionmark-comes-in-the-end-of-filename-when-i-create-txt-file-through-sh) is the link for the solution that I tried.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you think that a line like `my $text_file = print $';` does? (What it does is set $text_file to 1, because print returns 1).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response @TLP I read that this expression was for post-match  $'  so what I tried to do is to match the character "/" and tried to print the string following whatever was matched by the last successful pattern match which was "prokaryote_type_strain_report.txt" so that I do not have to provide input again to download the text file. I hope this answers your query.

Comment: @TLP yes I noticed it but could not  make out further what it mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$link` contains a newline character and the question mark is just a placeholder for such a non-printable character.

Try `chomp($link);`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is much flawed. I will go through some points.

```
my $path = abs_path();
```

Technically, in a simple program like this, you don't need to get the full path to where the program file is. You can just use a relative path and skip all this logic.

```
defined(my $link = <>) or die "unable to take arguments from command line $!";
```

This is incorrect. Because `<>` reads from either input file or stdin, it will likely always be defined, containing at least a newline, or an empty string. You might do something like:

```
chomp(my $link = <>);
die "Argument required" unless $link;
```

This

```
my $string = "$link";
```

Copying the input to a new variable is pointless. Using the double quotes to interpolate the variable into a string is also pointless.

```
$string  =~ s/(.*)\///;
my $text_file = print $';
```

You trim the input string, with a rather insecure regex, which will do "take any character 0 or more times, before a slash `/`, and replace with nothing. Store the matched characters in `$1` (because parentheses)".

Then you print `$'` the post match variable, which returns 1 to `$text_file`, because print always returns 1. You might just return `$'`, which might contain your file name. Or just use `$string`, which should contain the same thing since you removed everything up to the last slash.

```
getstore($link, "$path/links_ncbi/$text_file") or die "unable to get required text file $!\n";
rename("$path/links_ncbi/1", "$path/links_ncbi/$'") or die "unable to rename text file $!\n";
```

So now you `getstore` the file to the file name `1`, and then you rename the file from `1` to `$'`. Phew! This is complicated stuff.

Just skip all of this, and use something like

```
chomp(my $link = <>);
die "Argument required" unless $link;
my $filename = $link =~ s/.*\///r;     # remove path return file name
getstore($link, $filename);
```